# Cannot receive message from ActiveMQ with spring boot JMS

Tags: java, jms

I am new to Java coding ,and I was trying to receive an message from a queue,but I failed.I'd like to know why and please help me out!I copied almost all the codes from Spring boot Guide.
I only wrote this 3 java files (and 1 application.properties):Application.java,Receiver.java and JMSSettings.

**Receiver.java**

```
package receiver;

import javax.jms.Message;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import app.Application;

@Component
public class Receiver {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    @JmsListener(destination = "EMQ", containerFactory = "jmsContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Message m) {
       logger.info("Received an message:"+m);
    }

}
```

**Application.java**

```
package app;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Try it");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**JMSSettings.java**

```
package setting;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;


@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSSettings {



    @Bean
    JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
        jmsTemplate.setPriority(9);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }


}
```

**application.properties**

- spring.activemq.broker-url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616/)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=30&maxReconnectAttempts=3
- spring.activemq.pooled=true
- spring.activemq.user=admin
- spring.activemq.password=admin

The project started but when i send message to the queue,no message can be received.

**logger**

```
2016-11-14 18:06:07.380  INFO 9124 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-11-14 18:06:07.391  INFO 9124 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-11-14 18:06:07.457  INFO 9124 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-11-14 18:06:07.463  INFO 9124 --- [           main] app.Application                          : Started Application in 4.746 seconds (JVM running for 6.413)
```

the activeMQ web page shows that no active consumer.

I send message in the ActiveMQ page like "hello",but it is in Messages Enqueued ,not in Messages Dequeued

Comment: are you actually referring to the properties in your configuration? I can't see it above

Comment: yes sir,i thinks so ,i use spring-boot-configuration-processor in my pom...

Comment: I know its an old post but did you find a solution for that? I am having the same problem with my queues. I am not able to dequeue messages although I can see in debug logs that messages are enqueued

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. I can see the messages inside the queue.But somehow receiver is not able to retrieve the messages

Comment: I am also facing the same issues. Anyone got any solution for this issue?